# Error: The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, void

Tags: java

Al intentantar compilcar la clase que está a continuación recibo el error escrito en el título de la pregunta en la parte del toString.

Es la primera vez que he tenido este problema y por más que lo reviso e intento comparar con otros trabajos que he hecho anteriormente no consigo encontrar una solución a este error.

Anteriormente habia hecho otra pregunta relacionada al mismo tema con un código que no era el correcto, asi que vuelvo a postear con este código.

```
public class Estadistica
{
    
    private int cantidadCargamentos;
    private String cargamentoMasPesado;
    private String cargamentoMasLigero;
    private int promedio;
    private int calcularPromedio;  

    //Guarda la cantidad de cargamentos
    public void setCantidadCargamentos(int cantidadCargamentos)
    {
        this.cantidadCargamentos=cantidadCargamentos;
    }
  
    public int getCantidadCargamentos()
    {
        return cantidadCargamentos;
    }
    
    //Aumenta la cantidad de los cargamentos
    public String aumentarCantidadCargamentos()
    {
       cantidadCargamentos=cantidadCargamentos+1;
       return "Cargamento registrado.";
    }
    
    // Guarda el cargamento mas pesado
    public void setCargamentoMasPesado(String cargamentoMasPesado)
    {
        this.cargamentoMasPesado=cargamentoMasPesado;
    }

    
    public String getCargamentoMasPesado()
    {
        return "\n"+cargamentoMasPesado+"";
    }

    //Guarda el cargamento mas ligero
    public void setCargamentoMasLigero(String cargamentoMasLigero)
    {
        this.cargamentoMasLigero=cargamentoMasLigero;    
    }

    public String getCargamentoMasLigero()
    {
        return "\n"+cargamentoMasLigero+"";
     }    
    
    //Calcula promedio de peso los cargamentos
        
    public void setPromedio(int promedio)
    {
        this.promedio=promedio;
    }
    
    //calcularPromedio
    public void calcularPromedio(){
    int sumaPeso=0;
    promedio=cantidadCargamentos*100/sumaPeso;
  }
    
  

    //getPromedio
      public int getPromedio(){
        return promedio;
      } 
      
      //toString
      public String toString()
      {
            return "Cantidad de cargamentos: " +getCantidadCargamentos()+ "\n"+
            "Cargamento mas pesado: " +getCargamentoMasPesado()+ "kg \n"+
            "Cargamento mas ligero " +getCargamentoMasLigero()+ "kg \n"+
            "Promedio total del peso de los cargamentos: " +calcularPromedio();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tu método calcular promedio es un void no tiene un return por ende no podes concatenar un String con un método void

Comment: CalcularPromedio a mí parecer debería retornar un double

Comment: Tal como comenta Dramaturgo, basta con agregar `return promedio;` y definir el tipo devuelto por `calcularPromedio`. Otra opción es calcular el promedio en otro momento previo y en vez de hacer `promedio = ...`, haces `this.promedio = ...`. Luego, en vez de concatenar `calcularPromedio()` basta con concatenar `this.promedio`. Saludos

Comment: En vez de `calcularPromedio()` pon `this.promedio`, nos avisas si te funcionó.

Comment: No es necesario editar el título ni nada en la pregunta. SI ves, sale marcada como resuelta en todas las búsquedas gracias a que marcaste una respuesta como aceptada :)  Revirtiendo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método calcular promedio es un void no tiene un return por ende no puedes concatenar un String con un método void

**Solución 1:**
Agregar return promedio; y definir el tipo devuelto por calcularPromedio.

**Solución 2:**
calcular el promedio en otro momento previo y en vez de hacer promedio = ..., haces this.promedio = .... y en vez de concatenar calcularPromedio() basta con concatenar this.promedio